# MySQL Master - Slave syncs until I restart mysql on slave

Tags: mysql, master-slave

I configured two servers with the same version of MySQL (Server version: 5.6.15-log MySQL Community Server (GPL))

I configured everything and it started working updating the slave database from the master very fast.

Then I started to notice that the changes where not in the slave, I restarted mysql on the slave and the changes where there again.

So right now until I restart the mysql server on the slave it gets the changes from the master.

Comment: What is your specific question? It's difficult to tell what you want to know.

Comment: I guess that this is not how the sync should work, is something that I am missing or why is not updating the slave automatically